# HTML & CSS: How to put quotation mark and text in same height?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please show me how can I make a quotation like that (see the image)?

I have used the default html code for the quotation symbol:

```
<div>
<span style="font-size=30px">$#8220;</span>
<span style="font-size=12px">Test Text</span>
</div>
```

But this causes the quotation mark to be stay on top of the text but not at the same height of the text. Can someone please help me with this?

[image: Quotation Mark]

Comment: that effect is probably done with an image. If not, you can probably style it with the :first-letter psuedo element.

Comment: if you use Chrome to view the website (featuring the example you have the screenshot there) and right click on that quotation mark, then left click on "inspect" it will show you the HTML and CSS that goes together to make that happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the quote:

```
font-size: 30px;
display  : inline-block;
position : relative;
top      : 10px;
```

change the `top: 10px` to whatever you need to

Comment: Simply excellent. :) Thank you very much for so quick reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You will have to change the font to however you would like, but here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Zm23t/

This is kind of a play on 'Drop Caps' used in newspapers.

Comment: Thank you. That was the sort of thing I was looking for. I guess I'll be able to work around from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

..............

Hi now used to `pseudo` **css**  `:before` in css as like this

```
div span{
display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
div span:before{
content:'"';
  font-size:14px;
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[*Live demo*](http://tinkerbin.com/7cCAuE4l)**

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:30px">"</span>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;">
    <span style="font-size:12px">Test Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```